# In sed what does this mean?

Tags: sed

Can any one tell what does this following code signifies to in bash shell scripting?

```
sed -n 's/^.*\([Mm][Ss]_[^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: `man sed` will guid you

Comment: It calls the `sed` command?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. There are so many possible ways to interpret the question. Do you want to know what sed is, what the regex does, how capturing groups work, or what? It seems like either way the solution could be found by doing some reading of your own.

Comment: `bash` is irrelevant; this is a `sed` command that will work the same in any sh-style shell (and possibly others, as long as single-quoting is handled the same). It may depend, however, on what version of `sed` you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this text:

```
cat file
her ms_45 are you
MS_boat by ms US
What Ms_time are you
```

You will get all word starting with `ms_` case insensitive.

```
sed -n 's/^.*\([Mm][Ss]_[^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file
ms_45
MS_boat
Ms_time
```

The `sed` can even be shorten some from `sed -n 's/^.*\([Mm][Ss]_[^ ]*\).*/\1/p'` to:

```
sed -nr 's/.*([Mm][Ss]_[^ ]*).*/\1/p'
```

`-r` (regular expression), you do not need to escape the `()`
First `^` (start of line) is not needed, since `.*` grabs it.

---

You can also use  `grep` for this (simpler to understand):

```
grep -o '[Mm][Ss]_[^ ]*' file
ms_45
MS_boat
Ms_time
```

Get all words like this: (`M` or `m`) and (`S` or `s`) and `_` and all characters until space is found `[^ ]*`

**PS** The `sed` will only get the first `ms_..` of every line, but the `grep` get them all.